# immutable issues on android 13 using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin.forms for my android project. When I run the code to my mobile android 13, I got the following issue:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.fd.trucker.app: Targeting S+
> (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or
> FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if
> it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
> at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:401)
> at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:671)
> at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:658)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zzd(Unknown Source:18)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source:229)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(Unknown Source:0)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source:41)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.getToken(Unknown Source:56)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source:10)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzcfy(Unknown Source:4)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source:148)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent(Unknown
> Source:122)
> at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

But I have already added the immutable to the pending intent which place I have used.
1.

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(BootCompletedReceiver));
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
AlarmManager alarmManager = GetSystemService(AlarmService).JavaCast<AlarmManager>();
alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, BootCompletedReceiver.FirstReminder(), time, pending);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```

2. 

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);
var push = new Intent();
var fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, push, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
{
    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
}
else
{
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
}
notification.SetContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent)
         .SetContentTitle("Upgrade Failed")
         .SetContentText(Constants.DBUpgradeFailNotifications)
         .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
         .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
         .SetColor(0x0a384a)
         .SetAutoCancel(true);
manager.Notify(id, notification.Build());
```

3. 

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);
var push = new Intent();
var fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, push, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
{
    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
}
else
{
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
}
notification.SetContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent)
         .SetContentTitle("Destination Arrival")
         .SetContentText("It appears you've arrivedDestroy at the destination.Please enter the BL & Scale Ticket.")
         .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
         .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
         .SetColor(0x0a384a)
         .SetAutoCancel(true);
manager.Notify(id, notification.Build());
```

4. 

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.PutExtra("title", title);
intent.PutExtra("body", body);
intent.PutExtra("tripid", tripid);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("custom://" + SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis()));
var fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
{
    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
}
else
{
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
}
notification.SetContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent)
         .SetContentTitle(title)
         .SetContentText(body)
         .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
         .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
         .SetColor(0x0a384a)
         .SetAutoCancel(true)
         .SetOngoing(false);
manager.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(tripid), notification.Build());
```

5. 

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);
var push = new Intent();
var fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, push, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
{
    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
    chan1.LightColor = Color.Green;
    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
}
else
{
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
}
notification.SetContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent)
         .SetContentTitle(message.GetNotification().Title)
         .SetContentText(message.GetNotification().Body)
         .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
         .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
         .SetColor(0x0a384a)
         .SetAutoCancel(true);
manager.Notify(id, notification.Build());
```

6. 

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);
string title = "";
string body = "";
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
var i = p0 as Intent;
var bundle = i.Extras;
title = bundle.GetString("gcm.notification.title");
body = bundle.GetString("gcm.notification.body");
var tripid = bundle.GetString("key2");
intent.PutExtra("title", title);
intent.PutExtra("body", body);
intent.PutExtra("tripid", tripid);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("custom://" + SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis()));
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
{
    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
    chan1.LightColor = Color.Green;
    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
}
else
{
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
}
notification.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
         .SetContentTitle(title)
         .SetContentText(body)
         .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
         .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
         .SetColor(0x0a384a)
         .SetAutoCancel(true)
         .SetOngoing(false);
manager.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(tripid), notification.Build());
```

Please give me the solution for this one.

Comment: Hi, anyone please hep me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research about the error. Some people how met the issue: Its crashed due to lower version of Firebase Plugins and after upgrading the Android Dependencies and Flutter plugins it got resolved.

You can check this [link](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8018#issuecomment-1033577249) about Android 12 support for PendingIntents with the Immutable Flag.

In addition, you can check this comment about [make the sdk version lower](https://github.com/Iterable/iterable-android-sdk/issues/377#issuecomment-1006741121), it also fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you Guangyu Bai - MSFT, upgrade the firebase version is working for me